# Printer Brother MFC-J5730 no longer works

Tags: settings, networking, printer, ethernet

I have a printer Brother MFC-J5730 that has already worked on Elementary OS but suddenly it stops working, I can still control it via windows but not via OS.
In cups i have the mention (idle, accepting jobs, not shared, serverdefault) and it is indeed on-line (green indication), ip address is correct and I have already restarted the installation but without result.(The message is "the printer is unreachable at this time")
When I send out a print, the box that is being printed appears but nothing happens

Can somebody help me

Bruno

Comment: Hello ,
I have noticed that the problem is due to the installation of the latest updates, if I boot with a previous version of elementary (second choice at startup) the printer works perfectly, with the latest version it stops working.
I just wanted to let you know, not that it will yield anything because when one sees the questions circulating and the solutions that were given it is a sad thing, 0,0 support, Elementary looks good but nothing is being done to to help people out of need.

Answer (score 1):

I have noticed that the problem is due to the installation of the latest updates, if I boot with a previous version of elementary (second choice at startup) the printer works perfectly, with the latest version it stops working.
I just wanted to let you know, not that it will yield anything because when one sees the questions circulating and the solutions that were given it is a sad thing, 0,0 support, Elementary looks good but nothing is being done to to help people out of need.